# JavaScript Cell Does not Match Row

Tags: javascript, function, html-table, counter

I have a table where the user is able to add customers and when a customer is added, a unique ID is given to the row and each cell within the row.

As you can see, when you add a row, I have logged the `row.id` and the `cell.id`, however, the `cell.id` is supposed to be `'cell_' + rowCount + '_' + i` but the rowCount in the cell does not match the one in the row.

```js
// add customer or item
// append row to the HTML table
var rowCount = 1;
var cellCount = 0;

function appendRow(id, style) {
  var table = document.getElementById(id); // table reference
  length = table.length,
    row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length); // append table row
  row.setAttribute('id', style);
  var i;
  row.id = 'row' + rowCount;
  rowCount++
  // insert table cells to the new row
  for (i = 0; i < table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
    createCell(row.insertCell(i), i, 'cell_' + rowCount + '.' + i); // starts over when row changes
    cellCount++
  }
}

function createCell(cell, text, style) {
  var div = document.createElement('div'), // create DIV element
    txt = document.createTextNode('_'); // create text node
  div.appendChild(txt); // append text node to the DIV
  div.setAttribute('id', style); // set DIV class attribute
  div.setAttribute('idName', style); // set DIV class attribute for IE (?!)
  cell.appendChild(div); // append DIV to the table cell
  console.log(row.id + ' ' + div.id);
}
```

```css
table {
  text-align: center;
}
td  {
  width: 100px; 
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #fff;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<button id="addCust" class="addSort" onclick="appendRow('custList')">add customer</button>

<div class="custScroll">
  <table id="custListTop" contenteditable="false">
    <tr>
      <td style="border-top-left-radius: 5px;">Customers</td>
      <td>Work #</td>
      <td>Cell #</td>
      <td style="border-top-right-radius: 5px;">Main Location</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="custList" contenteditable="true">
    <tr>
      <td>Someone</td>
      <td>903-636-0000</td>
      <td>903-626-0000</td>
      <td>something</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

  `row.id = 'row' + rowCount;
  rowCount++`

followed by

`'cell_' + rowCount`

You are first using rowCount on the row when it's set to 1, then setting it to 2, then using it on the cell when it's set to 2.